# How to use special chars in the reactjs-chart label

Tags: reactjs, unicode, react-chartjs-2

I want to set accelerometer coordinates (
`ax`, `ay`, and `az` with `x`, `y`, and `z` subscript) in the reactjs-chartjs-2 label.
I can do only `ax`, using `a\u2093` (unicode),

```
{ label: 'a\u2093', color: '#ff0066'}
```

but I couldn't find anything for `ay` and `az` coords.
I found online this [link](https://www.htmlsymbols.xyz/miscellaneous-symbols/subscript-and-superscript).
Could you help me?

Comment: Perhaps post what code you have now/tried to allow the most appropriate focused answers.

Comment: Yes, a\u2093 works. No unicode for y and z (see the link above)

Comment: Please post all the code in the question so that you question remains viable if the linked page goes away. FWIW some including me will not visit random links in posts for a variety of reasons.

Comment: Where is labels? Dataset labels or xLabels or yLabels?

Comment: They are in the dataset labels